# php.js serialize function breaking on entity characters - UTF8 cause?

Tags: javascript, jquery, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters

OK, on my commerce platform, shopping cart data is stored as a serialized array in the session. An issue popped up today where one of the item's size options had special characters for 1/4 and 1/2 sizes, eg; 7¼, 7½ etc., However when viewing the order that a customer placed for this item, the size value showed up like so: 7Â½

Troublshooting 101, I took to the site and placed the exact same order the customer placed... oddly, everything worked as expected and the issue did not replicate. Then I noticed that the order was placed via a "phone order" which is a back-end script that allows the store staff to compile a new order and charge / finalize it all on one screen. The system does this via use of jquery and ajax stuff to keep everything on-screen without having to have multiple "checkout pages".

Anyway, placed the same order over the phone order script and the problem reproduced just fine. Taking a deeper look into things, I noticed that on the "site" side where customers place orders, the cart data is serialized using the PHP function, then base64_encoded and stored "COMPRESSED" as such in the database with the order.

On the phone order side, the serialization is done via a php.js serialize function that is suppose to emulate the php serialize function identically. The serialized data is then POSTED to a handler along with the customers information etc. The CC is charged and the order is saved to the database just like on the site side.

Looking into it further, I compared the two "serialized" strings from both sides for the same exact order and there is a difference. On php's side, the value 7½ is shown as "s:2:7½", the Javascript version is shown as "s:3:7½"...

I've verified that my site's character encoding is Western (iso-8859-1) on all pages involved in this process.

I was able to work around the issue... once the "bad" serialized object is passed to php to save the order, then I unserialize it, then pass the resulting array/object off to a recursive function that runs a converter function(char2html) on every value, it converts any special character to its entity name code, essentially ½ becomes &frac12; and Â becomes &Acirc;. I then use str_replace to get rid of any "&Acirc;" strings, then run it through another one of my functions(html2char) which coverts any &entityNames; back to their actual chcaracter.

Once that function is finshed running the object/array is then re-serialized using php's serialize function and everything works perfectly, no more Acric chars showing up on the orders placed on the phone order script.

So specifically I'm looking to figure out if there is some way I can force convert the UTF8 version of the ½ character in javascript to the 1 byte version (rather than the two byte UTF8 version that javascript is seeing), before I pass it to the serialize function in hopes that the serialize function will return the correct string, absent UTF8 characters.

That also being said there is some UTF8ness going on in the php.js serialize function but I'm not advanced enough in my JS coding to figure out if there is something *INSIDE* the serialize function doing this... or how to change it if there is.

Function reference:
http://phpjs.org/functions/serialize:508

Thoughts?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to make everything UTF-8 instead? That way you wouldn't have any character set problems EVER again. And you wouldn't need shaky str_replace workarounds for HTML entities 'n stuff. Also, obligatory reading: http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html.

Comment: Wouldnt I then need to convert my whole db to use utf8? re-save all my script files as utf8, update php to use mbstring and configured to run utf8, then have to update all my string functions to mb_variant? if wanted to go all UTF8 I suppose I could, just seems like more work than its worth since its an english site - I mean I might be missing something here but is there something to be gained by setting utf8 as the content type of the site if the ide/serverside parser/database were still using iso-8859?

Comment: Peace of mind, when someone wants to place an international order? Also, the conversion part can be quite automated. And the `mb_` functions will be necessary in very few places. Well, it's for you to judge, of course.

Comment: Yeah i'm considering it, I'm going to have to set up a whole new server to pre-test everything out. I cant just switch this on my production environment because if my code breaks (and there is a lot of it) then its going to be a nightmare. One of these days...